# How to save esri map as an image file

Tags: silverlight, dictionary, screenshot, pixel, esri

I am using Silverlight 3  and I am trying to take a screenshot of esri map.

I was able to take a screenshot and save as a file for silverlight controls, but when I try to access Esri map image, I get "Pixel access not allowed" error. I heard this is because of different domain (I am trying to get map image on the client side, and map image is not accessible at server side in my silverlight application).

**So I am trying to find a function from esri so that I can save the map image as a file.** 
does anybody know how to do this? or any other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a [script](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/silverlight/index.cfm?fa=codeGalleryDetails&scriptID=16697) from the Code Gallery for both printing and exporting map images.

The script requires a little bit of tweaking to get it to work (plus you need to dig a little bit into WCF and self-hosted services), but it has been working great for several months now. You can see it in action at our [web site](http://gustfront.ccrfcd.org/fvadvanced/fvadvanced.aspx).